# Google Calendar won't sync (Android 7)

Tags: google-account, google, google-calendar

I bought my phone originally in China so I installed all the Google Services later. 
Now I have some problems left:

- When I'm searching for my location on Maps it doesn't really work

But more important for me:

- My Google Calendar won't sync (and apparently neither my contacts), look at the screenshot - this was after I pressed *sync* and everything else synced:

[image]
Anyone an idea what I should look at in order to find out why after pressing *sync* those two didn't sync and what I could do about it?